# Saving data from form to database using TypeORM in Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM with angular to save form data to the database. The connection configuration is good as I can save data from the backend

```
{
   "type": "mssql",
   "host": "***",
   "port": ***,
   [...]
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   [...]
}
```

I can successfully save to the database running the code below

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import {createConnection} from "typeorm";
import {User} from "./entity/User";
[...]    
createConnection().then(async connection => {    
    console.log("Inserting a new user into the database...");
    const user = new User();
    user.firstName = "Timber";
    user.lastName = "Saw";
    user.age = 25;
    await connection.manager.save(user);
    console.log("Saved a new user with id: " + user.id);
    
    console.log("Loading users from the database...");
    const users = await connection.manager.find(User);
    console.log("Loaded users: ", users);
         
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

But I'm presently having issues trying to save data from a form(frontend). Here's my code

```
SubmitForm() {
//initialize connection with the database
this.connection.then(async connection=> {
  console.log("Inserting a new user into the database...");
  //create a new enrollee
  let enrollee = new Enrollee();
  enrollee.enrolleeTitle = this.PDTitle;
  enrollee.enrolleeLastName = this.PDSurname;
  enrollee.enrolleeFirstName = this.PDFirstname;
  enrollee.enrolleeOtherName = this.PDMiddlename;
  [...]
  let enrolleeRepo = connection.getRepository(Enrollee);

  //save info into database
  await enrolleeRepo.save(enrollee);
 console.log("Saved a new user with id: " + enrollee.id);
  //get all enrollees
  console.log("Loading enrollees from the database...");
  let enrollees = await enrolleeRepo.find();
  console.log("Loaded errollees: ", enrollees);
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

The project fails to build with tons of errors. Any guide will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this quite different than your approach.  I'm using Postgres but that shouldn't matter much but I'm using Nestjs to make it more like Angular.  It is a simpler setup than yours but Nestjs shouldn't make much difference either since it barely knows about TypeORM.

At the top of the controller after imports:

```
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  Post,
  Patch,
  Delete,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
  Body,
  Req,
  HttpCode,
  Param, Query
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { EnrolleesService } from './enrollees.service';
import { Enrollees } from './enrollees.entity';

@Controller('api/enrollee')  // /enrollee is the route
export class EnrolleeController {
  constructor(private readonly EnrolleeService: EnrolleeService) {}
```

Adding an item, user, whatever in the controller:

```
@Post()
  async addItem(@Req() req, @Body() recordData): Promise<Enrollees> {

    const result: Enrollees = await this.EnrolleesService.addItem(recordData);
    if (!result)
      throw new HttpException('Error adding new Enrollee', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    return result;
  }
```

In the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository, getManager, getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { Enrollees } from './enrollees.entity';


@Injectable()
export class EnrolleesService {

  private entityManager = getManager();

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Enrollees)
    private readonly enrolleesRepository: Repository<Enrollees>
  ) {}
async addItem(recordData): Promise<Enrollees> {
    return await this.enrolleesRepository.save(recordData);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the guide @Preston. Will make the changes and revert. Appreciate

Comment: my next challenge is mapping the form fields to the entity columns. How do i do this please @Preston

Comment: SO really isn't for tutoring, which I don't have time for, but when you setup the entity it will create the fields in your table, or add or delete them, at least with Postgres.  The entity is your data model.  It is magical, no mapping.

Comment: Yes I've created the entities in the entity folder created by typeorm. If you say its magical, I'll try it out @Preston. Thanks